# what error is prohibiting my react-native build for on device app execution?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm attempting to run a react-native app on my iphone which is functioning properly in the emulator.  I'm following the instructions (mostly) associated with 'using the offline bundle' here, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html

I ran

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output tmp/groups.bundle
```

which resulted in a terminal output of

```
--bundle-output tmp/groups.bundle
bundle: Created ReactPackager
bundle: Closing client
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: tmp/groups.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
Assets destination folder is not set, skipping...
```

Of course, 'assets destination skipping' is probably not a great message but I'm unclear how/where it is relevant in this process.

I'm generally unclear on what feedback to be considering inside xcode, I'm def not a seasoned ios dev, but consider this screenshot,

[image]

Is there an obvious detail that I'm missing?  I should caveat that I'm not 100% certain my device is provisioned correctly but I kind of generally get the impression that it is.

Comment: Can you get it to work without trying to make an offline bundle? To check;   in AppDelegate.m change the line that says localhost:8081 to the name or IP address of your host machine e.g. mymacbook.local:8081 then ensure that the packager is running on the host (as you do when running in the emulator) and push the build to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue earlier today. I did a combination of:

1. Update to v`0.14.2` `npm i --save react-native@0.14.2`
2. [Follow the upgrade guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#content) to update from `0.13` to `0.14`
3. Removed that App from the simulator and changed targets (I'm not sure why this is necessary, but I notice that it was working on the iPhone 6 simulator so I switched from iPhone 5. When I switching back to 5 it then worked.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT**

I was able to reproduce the error once again.

When testing in the simulator if you build and run **OPTION 1**, then build **OPTION 2**. You will get this error.

It seems that the App isn't completely updating when switching between the two options.

The solution is to remove the App and let the build process reinstall it.

Comment: I should have stated and will update accordingly but I'm working off react-native 0.14.1, I'm a bit unclear about your post as well, are you in all cases referring to running the app on a connected device or switching the context of what kind of emulator to be using? I find myself leary about a solution that involves reloading the app. that and I haven't tried OPTION 1 so again, unclear.  I'm going to keep tinkering.  Thanks for the post.